# Jenkins ssh-agent troubleshooting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, openssh, ssh-agent

**The Problem**
The *Jenkins SSH Agent Plugin* is failing to successfully load a key with a passphrase that is stored with the *Credentials Plugin*. The Jenkins Agent is running on the same machine as the Controller.

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing@tmp/askpass_11086250741160980548.sh): No such file or directory
```

The error seems to be saying that the script used to load the passphrase doesn't exist.  I don't know if it exists or how to test that, as I'm assuming it's meant to be deleted quickly. I can verify the script is not there after a run, but that's expected. Therefore, I'm not sure if the problem is with the *SSH Agent Plugin*, or *Credentials Plugin* or a combination/interaction of both plugins.

**The ssh-agent Binary on the Host Works**
The problem does not seem to be with the host system, as I am able to successfully use `ssh-add` from the command line with the referenced key and passphrase.

**The SSH Agent Plugin Partially Works**
The username, private key and passphrase have been added into the Jenkins Controller utilizing the Credentials Plugin. The SSH Agent Plugin works as expected with a plugin that ***does not*** have a passphrase.

**Current Environment**

- RHEL7
- Jenkins 2.359
- SSH Agent Plugin Version 295.v9ca_a_1c7cc3a_a_
- Credentials Plugin Version 1143.vb_e8b_b_ceee347
- OpenSSH_8.8p1a

**My pipeline is simple**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    stages {
        stage("setup environment") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            } //steps
        } //stage - setup environment
        stage("Test the key") {
            steps {
                sshagent(['testkey']) {
                    sh "ssh host whoami"
                } //sshagent
            } //steps
        } //stage - Test the key
    } //stages
} //pipeline
```

**The output looks like this**

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials testkey (Test key with passphrase)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-oKcZZF65GvXc/agent.31647
SSH_AGENT_PID=31650
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
ssh_askpass: exec(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing@tmp/askpass_11086250741160980548.sh): No such file or directory
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
.
.  (I removed the extraneous output showing the closing of each section.)
.
ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've found similar issues where Jenkins was having issues interacting with the ssh-agent tools, however this isn't the case here.  The indicated problem is with the script that (I'm guessing) provides the key and passphrase to ssh-agent.

For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565578/ssh-askpass-exec-usr-bin-ssh-askpass-no-such-file-or-directory-permission-de) describes an issue with the `ssh-askpass` binary while executing `ssh-add` on the client.

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
```

In my scenario, `ssh-add` is being executed by the `ssh-agent` plugin on the Jenkins Controller, which is where the Jenkins Agents are launched. And the error isn't with the `ssh-askpass` binary, but rather the `@tmp/askpass_####.sh` script that Jenkins generates to interact with `ssh-askpass`.

Some posts with slightly different symptoms suggest removing or adding trailing newlines when adding the private key to the Jenkins web UI.  I have tried this with no success.

- **Is there a way to test things further?**
- **Is there more logging that I can turn on?**
- **What is the experiment that would isolate a component and expose the root cause?**

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879395/ssh-askpass-exec-app-jenkins-slave-workspace-footmp-askpass-foo-sh-no-such), however I have added additional information in hopes that I'm clearly stating the issue and the surrounding context.

Comment: shooting int the dark: do you have selinux enabled (`getenforce`)?